# how to fix Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 404

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

```
function amongst_few_script() {
  
  var wrkBk = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var wrkSht= wrkBk.getSheetByName("Data");
  
  
  var formURL = ""
  var formData = ""
  
  var Product_Title = "";
  var SKU = "";
  var Size = "";
  var First_Name = "";
  var Last_Name = "";
  var E_mail = "";
  var Phone_Number = "";
  
  var noOfRows = 101;
  
  for (i=2;i<=noOfRows;i++)
  {
    Product_Title = wrkBk.getRange("A" + i).getDisplayValue();
    SKU = wrkBk.getRange("B" + i).getDisplayValue();
    Size = wrkBk.getRange("C" + i).getDisplayValue();
    First_Name = wrkBk.getRange("D" + i).getDisplayValue();
    Last_Name = wrkBk.getRange("E" + i).getDisplayValue();
    E_mail = wrkBk.getRange("F" + i).getDisplayValue();
    Phone_Number = wrkBk.getRange("G" + i).getDisplayValue();
    
    formURL = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeyxUHdX_4fLoE6i2fdPD6RbpK5Wg-5OY05TatdQHrg-jEV5g/FormResponse?&pageHistory=0"
    formData = "&entry.1089277187=" + Product_Title + "&entry.742914399=" + SKU + "&entry.2011436433=" + Size + "&entry.638818998=" + First_Name + "&entry.1952962866=" + Last_Name + "&entry.916445513=" + E_mail + "&entry.848461347=" + Phone_Number
    
    var finalURL = formURL + formData
      
      var  options = {
        "method": "post"
      };
    
    
    UrlFetchApp.fetch(finalURL, options); 
      
  }
  
    
  
  
}
```

whenever i run the script i get this command and idk what to do tbh Exception: Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 404. Truncated server response: <meta name="viewport" c... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 40, file "Code")
someone can help please?

Answer (score 1):

You can suppress these kinds of errors by adding **"muteHttpExceptions": true** in your **options** variable. Please see modified options variable below. I replicated your code and applied this and it worked on my end:

```
  var  options = {
    "method": "post",
    "muteHttpExceptions": true
  };
```